# Java - Method Overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I am having a trouble with Method Overloading I was ask to create a program that will enter an operator and 2 operands. Overload the method named **getAnswer** as follows: 
    -

1. get its **sum** by calling the method
2. get its **difference** by calling the method and pass the operands on that method.
3. get its **product** by calling the method and returns a value.
4. get its **quotient** by calling a method and returns a value and pass the operands on that method.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodHomework2
{
    int a, b;
    public void getAnswer()
    {
        int sum = a + b;
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    }
    public void getAnswer(int a, int b)
    {
        int diff = a - b;
        System.out.println("The difference is: " + diff);
    }
    public int getAnswer()
    {
        int prod = a * b;
        return prod;
    }
    public int getAnswer(int a, int b)
    {
        int quot = a / b;
        return quot;
    }
    public static void main (String args[])
    {   
       MethodHomework2 mh = new MethodHomework2();
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
       int returnValue;

       System.out.print("Enter 2 number: ");
       a = kb.nextInt();
       b = kb.nextInt();

        mh.getAnswer();
        mh.getAnswer(c, d);
        returnValue = mh.getAnswer();
        System.out.println("The product is: " + returnValue);
        returnValue = mh.getAnswer(c, d);
        System.out.println("The quotient is: " + returnValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to overload your methods for this.

Comment: when calling `getAnswer ()` - how would it know which one to use?

Comment: And what behavior are you seeing? What is the problem?

Comment: `getAnswer()` for **diff** and `getAnswer()` for **quot** is not the way overloading is done as they both have **same signature**

Comment: Passing the different types of argument lists only make the signature of method be unique. So try different datatypes to achieve method overloading. Otherwise, the manipulation you are doing in your program seems like operator overloading. The simple way to remember this Overloading is compiler time polymorphism and the compiler would never allow duplication of variables where methods with same arguments and different return types or different access modifier are considered as duplicate methods.

Comment: Also found an error that you didn't declare the Class members **c** and **d** anywhere else in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look to [Overloading Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures.
>   This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they
>   have different parameter lists.
>
> Overloaded methods are differentiated by the number and the type of
>   the arguments passed into the method.

In your code example, `int getAnswer()` and `int getAnswer(int a, int b)` are distinct and unique methods because they require different parameter lists.

> The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating
>   methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature
>   even if they have a different return type.

There will be compilcation error when you declare method of `void getAnswer()` and `int getAnswer()` since the 2 methods are declared with same signature:

```
java: method getAnswer() is already defined in class MethodHomework2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method Overloading**

Same name different parameters

```
myMethod(int x)
myMethod(int x, int y)
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, there is `three different ways` to method overloading.

1. By changing the number of parameters in two methods.

   ```
   void add(){}

   void add(int a){}
   ```
2. By changing data types of the parameters of methods.

   ```
   void add(int a){}

   void add(float a){}
   ```
3. By changing Order of the parameters of methods.

   ```
   void add(int a, String b){}

   void add(String a, int b){}
   ```